# Where can I find GDAL bindings for Python 3.3?

Tags: python, gdal

I have been using GDAL 1.9.x on Python 2.7 and took the bindings from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/). Is there a place to get GDAL bindings for Python 3.3 or is GDAL not officially supported in Python 3.3 yet?

Comment: I didn't verify it, but this SO question&answer seems to answer this question for Ubuntu: [Installing GDAL Python binding in Ubuntu to use as standalone module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31655333/1801588).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found [this](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) page to download GDAL from, providing that you use Windows. In the top-most table, click one of the two links at the bottom that fits your system (Win32 or Win64). There you can find the core-file and bindings for at least Python 3.2. I can't seem to find anything about Python 3.3 though.

If you need some advice on how to fix everything, [this great blog post](https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/) is my source.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have been to Tamas's site but did not notice the bindings before. While we are still not seeing Py33, I will settle for Py32 now, and was able to get GDAL working.